# Sprites textures behave like the same texture. Java libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to make robots that are walking left or right, depends from property from Tiledmap. Walking works fine but I have issue with texture facing. Every robot's texture is facing the same as the last robot's texture, like they were using the same texture. To set texture I'm using `region = Assets.instance.robotsAnimations.robotOne.getKeyFrame(timer);` and every robot seams to use the same texture instead of his new own texture. How to deal with it?

Comment: Can you show more of your code please. The Robot class and where you update and render the robots.

Comment: @Morchul [Here is robot code](http://www.wklejto.pl/621488?mode=txt&language=java) and [Assets code](http://www.wklejto.pl/621492) 
and [images](https://imgur.com/llbLXBY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Robots use the same TextureRegion.
You have static `Assets` class which holds one instance of `RobotsAnimations` and all Robots point to the same Animation in `RobotsAnimations`.
So when one flip the region of the Animation all other Robots use also the flipped one.
Create your Animation in the Robot class so every Robot has his own Animation:

```
public RobotOne(PlayScreen playScreen, Rectangle rect, boolean right){
        ...

        timer = 0;
        TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(Assets.instance.animationSheet,Assets.instance.animationSheet.getWidth() / cols, Assets.instance.animationSheet.getHeight() / rows);
        TextureRegion[] animationFrames = new TextureRegion[cols * rows];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                animationFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }
        ownAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1/15f, animationFrames, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP)
        region = ownAnimation.getKeyFrame(timer);

        ...
    }
```

When you use TexturePacker there is an easier way to create animations:
[Libgdx Animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959627/libgdx-animation-not-working/52074648#52074648)

Comment: I was thinking so, and have done like you write. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because you are calling getKeyFrame method  for both robots with same timer. getKeyFrame method returns the animation respected texture by timer. To solve this you should have separate  timer variable for each robot and make the timer zero on moving direction change.

Comment: Every robot has his own timer. The point is that all robots seems to share one region instead to have their own and every robot texture is flipped like the last robot's texture from array.

Comment: Could you Give more detail of your code? and can you explain more detail of your problem? sending screenshots may help a lot.